# How to Create Multiple Vue Apps Under One Project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, hosting

I'm new to Vue js and I'm developing an e-commerce project with firebase. I saw in firebase there are multiple hosting features which will help me to host client and admin side in two different domains. I don't know how to create two apps in one project folder like this [example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/create-multiple-angular-apps-under-one-project-ff44541a259b) in angular. If any knows please share your thoughts

Answer (score 3):

Follow this

#### Step 0 - Firebase setup

---

In this tutorial **my-app** is my Firebase project id
**my-app-public** Web App is associate to **my-app** Hosting site (default hosting site takes the project id as name)
**my-app-admin** Web App is associate to **my-app-admin** Hosting site

#### Step 1

---

Move your public and admin apps in a new directory

```
my-app/
├── public-site/
└── admin-site/
```

#### Step 2

---

Init from **my-app/** with firebase and of course select Hosting feature to set up

```
firebase init
```

Do not pay attention to firebase asking for the public name folder

#### Step 3

---

Set the build path of your apps to the targets public and admin.
Edit the **firebase.json** file and add your apps.

```
{
    "hosting": [
        {
          "target": "public",
          "public": "public-site/dist",
          "ignore": [
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "admin",
          "public": "admin-site/dist",
          "ignore": [
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
    ],
}
```

#### Step 4

---

Link the targets to yours Firebase Hosting Sites. (Hosting Site != Web App)
Edit the **.firebaserc**, if it doesn't exist create it at the root of my-app/

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "my-app", # firebase project id
  },
  "targets": {
    "my-app": { # firebase project id
      "hosting": {
        "public": [
          "my-app" # public hosting site id
        ],
        "admin": [
          "my-app-admin" # admin hosting site id
        ]
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Now if you type

```
firebase target
```

You should get

```
[ hosting ]
public (my-app)
admin (my-app-admin)
```

#### Step 5

---

Build your both apps

```
cd public-site/
npm run build
```

Make sure your apps are build in the dist/ folder

#### Step 6

---

Deploy both apps

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Or deploy only the public app

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:public
```

Your apps should be deployed to

- https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/
- https://my-app-admin.firebaseapp.com/

#### BONUS - Build and deploy your apps on merge on master (Github)

---

First use

```
firebase init hosting:github
```

and follow the CLI instructions, it should ask your repo
One it's done check if your repo has the firebase service account key

- Go on your **github repo > settings > security**
- And you should see a secret env variable named **FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MY_APP**

Let's setup your github workflow in your project, remove the .yml files in **.github/workflows** generated by the previous command and create your own workflow (file name doesn't matter):

```
name: Deploy on PROD to Firebase Hosting
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master # branch to target
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies & build public-site
        run: npm ci && npm run build
        working-directory: public-site
      - name: Install dependencies & build admin-site
        run: npm ci && npm run build
        working-directory: admin-site
      - name: Deploy websites
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MY_APP }}' # edit here
          projectId: my-app # edit here
          channelId: live
```

So every push/merge on master will be build each apps and deploy them on Firebase Hosting